# Slick text transitions for game tutorial

Tags: text, games, tutorial, transitions

Are there any names for the techniques/transitions used to make text appear in a slick, and attention grabbing (but unobtrusive) way?

A typical use case for this is the tutorial level of a game, which (in tutorial mode) constantly pops up instructions as the user encounters new features.  So, the instructions should grab the users attention without looking clunky.

Typically it's a combination of expanding and fading, plus maybe a flashing button which is clicked to dismiss the text.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by 'names'. Have a look at [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) for a reference to many common animation names. I've also removed the request for JAVA implementations suggestions - [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) would be the place for this type of question.

Comment: Fair enough re. java.  Your Animate.css answers my question, that's what I mean by names.

Comment: I've added an answer based on the comment so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) for a list of common animation names.